# Create bubble.json file for render geo tiff file on autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, tile, geotiff

I'm want to manage a big geo tiff files on autodesk forge viewer. I'm following this approach [Viewing Large OCR/Terrain Images in Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewing-large-ocrterrain-images-forge-viewer), of creating tiles to avoid load a big file.

my questions are, how to divide the geotiff file into  small tiles? and once I have the tiles created, how to create the file bubble.json to manage all the tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Divide your image into tile sizes of 256x256, into an image pyramid.  Follow section "part2 - Converting a large image" and use your TIFF image.

I use the 'convert' command from imagemagick in a script (see https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewing-large-ocrterrain-images-forge-viewer)

Use this bubble.json file, and modify it: https://github.com/wallabyway/pdf-imageviewer/blob/master/docs/topo/bubble.json

Let me know if something is not clear.
Cheers